# Split between deliminator in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to split a percentage using excel formulas. I am trying to get the first portion of the percent before the "-" and the second portion of the percent after the "-".

`L16 = 1-7%` will cause this to work perfect fine.

`L16 = 19-100%` will cause the formula to break. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the second portion to work.

I have created 2 formulas.
Grabs first half:

```
=LEFT(L16,SEARCH("-",L16,1)-1)
```

Grabs second half(the one not working):

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(L16,SEARCH("-",L16,1)+0),LEN(RIGHT(L16,SEARCH("-",L16,1)+0))-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE()` for a quick solution:

For the left part:

```
=LEFT(E2,SEARCH("-",E2)-1)
```

and the right:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)-SEARCH("-",E2)),"%","")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(L16,LEN(L16)-SEARCH("-",L16)),"%","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one formula for both:

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($L16,"%",""),"-",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A1)-1)*999+1,999))
```

Put that in the first cell and copy over one and down the data set

[image]

---

And if you want them as percentages then use this:

```
=--(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($L16,"%",""),"-",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A1)-1)*999+1,999)) & "%")
```

And format the cells as percentages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I copied your formula it worked for me, but then I realized that I put a space on either side of the hyphen.  So there is something about the spaces that makes it work, in case that helps you troubleshoot how to fix your formula (I'd leave this as a comment if I had enough rep, sorry).